# Using awk or sed in Mac OS

Tags: macos, bash, sed, awk

I have a file of about 150 lines, where each line is part of a URL. I wanted to extract 4 different parameters from each of the lines and put them into a file. Something like:

```
/secure/domain/new.aspx?id=620&utm_source=1034&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=term1&try=1&v=3&utm_account=account_name&utm_campaign=campaign_name&utm_adgroup=adgroup&keyword=keyword1&pkw=pkw1&idimp=id&premt=premt1&gclid=id
```

As a trial, I did

```
awk '/pkw/,/&idimp/' file > output.txt
```

thinking that this would atleast get me value1, but it just returned the input file as is. What am I doing wrong? Also, how to make it return all four values? I'm looking to get keyword, pkw, idimp and premt.

**Edit:** The expected output is a file containing the 4 values for each of the 150 lines in the input file. So

```
 keyword pkw1 idi premt1
```

Even if I just get the 4 values in 4 different files, it would suffice.

Comment: That will print the entirety of any line that falls between a line containing the string `param1` and a line containing the string `param2`. You need an action statement which does something different than printing the entire line if you want just parts of a line. You likely also want to only match on lines that contain the params you want (and not a range of lines).

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s='/helloworld/some/other/standard/URL/mumbo/jumbo/page.aspx?strings&that&I&am&not&interested&in&param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3&param4=value4&some&more&uninteresting&strings'
echo "$s" | grep -o 'param[1234]=[^&]*' | cut -d= -f2- | paste -d " " - - - -
```

```
value1 value2 value3 value4
```

---

Keeping up with the clarifications to the question:

```
s='/secure/domain/new.aspx?id=620&utm_source=1034&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=term1&try=1&v=3&utm_account=account_name&utm_campaign=campaign_name&utm_adgroup=adgroup&keyword=keyword&pkw=pkw1&idimp=id&premt=premt1&gclid=id'
echo "$s" |  grep -o '\<\(keyword\|pkw\|idimp\|premt\)=[^&]*' | cut -d= -f2- | paste -d " " - - - -
```

```
keyword pkw1 id premt1
```

The `\<` is a "start of word" anchor to avoid matching parameters like "fookeyword"

With awk, I'd write:

```
awk -F '[?=&]' '
    BEGIN {
        # initialize the parameters you want
        p["keyword"] = p["pkw"] = p["idimp"] = p["premt"] = 1
    } 
    {
        for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) 
            if ($i in p) 
                printf "%s ", $(i+1)
        print ""
    }
'
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked on the first attempt! :)

Comment: Hey glenn, I got the output yesterday and had to do some more tr-ing and sed-ing to get it exactly the way I wanted it. While I didn't expect it to be exactly easy, I assume there's an easier way. So, I got the 4 keywords newline separated, with an extra newline at the end of each group of 4. Any way that could have been tab separated and newline separated, or comma and newline separated?

Comment: with `paste -d " " - - - -` the -d option defines the separator between the fields. If you want a comma use `-d ,`. If you want a tab, omit that option since tab is paste's default separator

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -F'[=&]' '{print $2, $4, $6, $8}' file
value1 value2 value3 value4
```

To redirect the output to a file:

```
awk -F'[=&]' '{print $2, $4, $6, $8}' file > output.txt
```

**EDIT:** Based on your edited question you can use:

```
awk -F'[=&]' '{n=1; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i=="interested") {n=i+3; break}}
      for (i=0; i<8; i+=2) printf $(n+i) " "; print ""}' file
value1 value2 value3 value4
```

Comment: I would avoid the `+`. If there's an empty value `param3=&param4=x` you'll see "corrupted" output.

Comment: Thanks I edited but I had `'[=&]+'` for the case if 2 `&&` appear by any chance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited the question. Can you please edit the answer accordingly? I tried changing the `[=&]` to include some pattern matching, but didn't work out as expected.

Comment: It's not getting me the exact output. Let me change the question to reflect what the closest URL is, as I can't share the exact URL.

Answer (score 0):

Or just `grep -P`, but that probably requires installing GNU grep.

```
grep -oP '[?&][^&?=]+=\K[^&?]+'
```