# grep command equivalent in Java

Tags: java, regex, grep

So, I have this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957621/using-awk-or-sed-in-mac-os/), which has been answered. I'm looking to replicate the marked answer in Java. Is there any way I can do some/most/all of it in Java?

Comment: I don't know. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: Tried doing it in Java, you mean? I've been looking around for a solution, but nothing I saw does what the grep command does.

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062954/extract-sub-string-between-two-certain-words-using-regex-in-java. That would be ideal, except that I need to capture 4 different strings as opposed to only one that the poster of that question is trying to get.

Comment: You could go with http://stackoverflow.com/a/13592567/1266906

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Do you happen to know if it works with partial URLs? As you can see, the URL does not really have a "http://..." in front of it.

Comment: @TheConstructor, please make your comment the answer. It worked perfectly. I'll mark it as the right answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course Java can be used to replace grep as seen e.g. [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222659/java-grep-library).

As you really want extract parameter values from a URL you could e.g. go with [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13592567/1266906), where a simple Java-function returns all parameters and their values as a Map. If you already use a HTTP-related library you may also want to look if they included a similar function.